# What would happen if my computer shuts down while BitLocker is encrypting my OS partition?

Tags: crash, shutdown, bitlocker

The title is the question.
I am now enctypting a 107 GB partition and it takes ages. I am dying to know what would happen if the encryption was stopped by, let's say, a thermal shutdown or if the power went off?
I'd rather not try it myself, so I am asking you. (I hope it did not happen to you!)

And, if this happens, how can I get it fixed?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found this: [BitLocker Drive Encryption in Windows 7: Frequently Asked Questions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee449438(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_TurnOff)

According to Microsoft TechNet, you would be just fine.

Comment: I was recently unfortunate enough to experience this on a Windows 8 installation. I got a bluescreen during the encryption of the OS drive. It is simply unable to boot up anymore. I am asked for the BitLocker password when I boot up, I type it, it validates it correctly, then black, and all the LEDs on the computer stay on.

Comment: This happened to me too. It crashed almost immediately, and then would refuse to let me in, even though I had the recovery key. No Windows recovery program was able to help me, and CHKDSK D: /R didn't work, since the disk was marked as RAW. I managed to get all my files back by using testdisk from an Ubuntu USB drive...

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me. I hard-reset the computer half way through decrypting, and when Windows came back up, it tried to resume decryption. It failed almost immediately with an error saying to run CHKDSK /R. After running that, the BitLocker decryption resumed and completed, without me even needing to restart the computer. There was no data loss, and I didn't have to repair anything besides the CHKDSK repair.

Answer (score 1):

It would partially corrupt your disk, nothing less, nothing more. It's important to defer the process before shutting down/restarting, gracefully or otherwise, as otherwise quite literally half your disk will be encrypted, and half won't. That's not a good situation to recover from, especially since it will be likely encrypting on the fly whilst it encrypts the partition.

Comment: Yes, I've figured that out. But any more specific effects? F.E. Will the OS boot? Can I use a recovery CD?

Comment: I've not tried it myself (for obvious reasons), but as far as I would imagine: the OS will not boot, a recovery CD will not help, you *may* be able to recover some data, but it would all be from the unencrypted part.

Comment: Good thing that I have an unencrypted partition.